# iOS CocoaPods: Getting Error while installing webSocket

Tags: ios, websocket, cocoapods

I have downloaded WebSocket SDK for ios from, 
https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example

Now when I tried to install cocoa pods I got following error

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] An error occurred while performing `git pull` on repo `master`.
[!] /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only

error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: early EOF

fatal: index-pack failed
```

Please help me for this.

Thanks.

Comment: http://edmondscommerce.github.io/git/during-git-pull-error-rpc-failed-result56-http-code-200-x-kibs-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly.html

Comment: use this for socket in iOS :- https://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient